# Input an arbitrary number of strings from the user

Tags: c, string, file-io

I want to read in an arbitrary number of strings, one at a time, using `<stdio.h>` in C.
I know that you can do this with integers using:

```
while (scanf("%d ", &integer))
```

but I cannot do:

```
while (scanf("%s", string))
```

How can I implement the above?

The input is on separate lines.

Comment: Don't ever use `scanf("%s")` - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921

Comment: You can use scanf if you bound the string size (per the answer you link to).

Comment: What do you want to do with each string after you've read it?  Using `scanf("%s", ...)` is going to give you a new white space separated word on each iteration of the loop, but presumably you're going to do something with the value read before reading the next.  That 'something' will dictate how you handle the storage of the next word.

Comment: i want to create a binary tree from an input bitstring so scanf("%s"...) then creare binary tree for that string, then move on to the next string untill there are no more strings in the input

Comment: okay maybe i asked that question badly

Comment: Don't test `scanf()` only for `false` (0) or `true`. `scanf()` will return `EOF` in case of failure by exhausting the input which your test won't catch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read an input string of unknown length?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16870485/608639)

Answer (score 3):

You *usually* want to use `fgets` to read input as strings, especially when you want one line of input to end up as one string.

You *can* also use `fscanf` with a scanset conversion to read a line at a time, such as:

```
char line[100], newline;

fscanf("%99[^\n]%c", line, &newline);
```

Then you can check whether `newline=='\n'` to determine whether you've read the entire line successfully, or the line was larger than the buffer you provided.

When you're trying to read line-oriented input, you normally want to avoid "%s" (even with a specified length) though, as this reads white-space delimited tokens, not entire lines.

Comment: fgets will not recognise hitting simply enter either :(

Comment: Oh yes it will!  `fgets()` will recognize a simple enter; it will be an 'empty' line, consisting of just the newline character.

Comment: @WasiqKashkari: What do you mean "won't recognize it"? It will read it as a string containin only a `new-line`.

Comment: i dont know, if i hit just enter, the scanf doesnt return, so if i debug it, hitting enter wont let the debugger step to the next line of code

Comment: @JerryCoffin [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394262/input-strings-into-c-in-a-loop) i think i asked it better here

Comment: @WasiqKashkari: Like I said -- to read line-oriented input, you *usually* want to use `fgets`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin so use while (fgets(...) == 1) ??

Comment: @WasiqKashkari: Usually you want `while (fgets(...) != NULL)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a char array:

```
char charArray[100];
while (scanf("%s", &charArray))
```

Comment: 4 is a little short, isn't it?  And you don't want the `&` in front of `charArray`.  I'd recommend `scanf("%99s", charArray)` to protect against buffer overflow.

Comment: Can you say "buffer overflow", little Juergen? :-)

Comment: no using a char array doesnt work. the while loop never finishes

Comment: i want it so if the user simply hits enter, the while loop finishes??

Comment: @WasiqKashkari If you want just one line of input, use `fgets()`.  It's much simpler to deal with than `scanf()`.

Comment: nope nope == 1 wont work either, if i hit enter, scanf will not recognise that this is input, it still expects some kind of character

Comment: @WasiqKashkari: Oh - yes...I remember now why I never use `scanf()`; it is just too damn hard to get it to work correctly.  Especially if the input should be regarded as 'line based'; it is just the wrong tool for the job.  Use `fgets()` or `getline()`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is to terminate the loop. `scanf` returns the number of successful scanned elements. In case of a string, also the empty string is successful scanned. Thus, you need another criterion, e.g.

```
 while(scanf("%s",string)  && (strlen(string)!=0))
```

Comment: nope nope, the scanf doesnt recognise hitting enter as input.

Answer (score 0):

I did not completely understand what you were trying to do from your original question. When you said you wanted to read in an arbitrary number of strings, I took that to mean, you wanted your program to be able to read 0 to n strings. Unfortunately in C, you will either have to cap off the maximum number of strings you would ever want to read in like 
`#define MAX_NUMBER_OF_STRINGS_TO_READ 25`, or get into some sophisticated memory allocation scheme to read a string in and then add it to dynamic memory (returned from malloc).

I took the cap the maximum number of strings approach and wrote the following snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char charArray[5][25] = {0};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int in_idx = 0;
    int out_idx = 0;

    printf("\n\n%s\n", "Enter no more than 5 strings, no more than 25 characters long.");

    while(fgets (charArray[in_idx], 25, stdin))
    {
        if('\n' == charArray[in_idx][0])
        {
            printf("%s\n", "Entry terminated with newline.");
            break;
        }

        in_idx++;
    }

    for(out_idx=0; out_idx < (in_idx + 1); out_idx++)
    {
        printf("%s", charArray[out_idx]);
    }

    printf("\n%s\n", "Program ended.");

    return 0;
}
```

I made the termination character a newline. If I only want two strings, I press Enter when I've entered the second string. I terminated fgets by looking for a '\n' in the first position of the character array.